# How to make select box field(CCK) readonly in drupal 6?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, cck

I want to make the select box (CCK)field read only not to disabled so that i can get that field in the submit. i have tried it for the text fields using the following code :

```
$form['field_example'][0]['value']['#attributes']['readonly'] = 'readonly';
```

But for the select box i couldn't. Hardly i can only disable it. so is there any way to make it read only?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Nop, that will not work!
You need to write hook_form_alter, with correct formid, make the field '#disabled' => TRUE,

Comment: hi joshi, thanks for your valuable answer. yes i have done it through hook_form_alter ['#attributes']['disabled']='disabled'; but can i get the select field value in form_state['values'] once i disabled it.? thanks in advance.

Comment: Please correct it -- its not '#disabled' => 'disabled' but its '#disbled' => TRUE, You also forgot '#' in the attribute. Also, it will not be under '#attributes' but a separate propery. Please have a look at form api on Drupal.org